# power automate desktop - convert list into data table

Tags: list, power-automate-desktop

I read some text from a pdf into Power automate desktop. It is in the form of a list like

```
0 | 123 Testing Company 23.00
1 | Generation Z Co 555.11
2 | Tea Company 1,234.99
```

I need to separate the list into columns where the number at the end of the element is in its own column like

```
0 | 123 Testing Company | 23.00
1 | Generation Z Co     | 555.11
2 | Tea Company         | 1,234.99
```

Is there a way to do this? I've tried to `extract tables from PDF` instead but this method does not return the right data, because it seems PAD doesn't recognize it as a table.

Is there a way to convert a list into a data table?

Answer (score 0):

The only way seems to be to `For Loop` the List,
`Parse Text` each of the columns
and insert them each as a row to the Data table.

i feel like there should be a quicker way to do this.